# Installing MarkLogic 8 on CentOS 6.7 x64 via DigitalOcean

Tags: installation, marklogic, digital-ocean, centos6.5, marklogic-8

## Installing MarkLogic 8 on CentOS 6.7 x64 via DigitalOcean

Okay so I downloaded the rpm file from:
`https://developer.marklogic.com/download/binaries/8.0/MarkLogic-8.0-3.2.x86_64.rpm`

I installed it with:
`sudo yum install MarkLogic-8.0-3.2.x86_64.rpm`

Started it:
`sudo /etc/init.d/MarkLogic start`

Went to admin interface:
`my_ip_address:8001`

I skip joining a cluster
I type in admin for user
Type in a password and confirm it
Realm is public
I click OK and...

I get redirected to:
`my_ip_address:8001/security-install-go.xqy`

And get this:
No data received

ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
Hide details
Unable to load the webpage because the server sent no data.
Reload this webpage
Press the reload button to resubmit the data needed to load the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, someone else ran into this and after investigating everything else I tried, this was the answer:
http://developer.marklogic.com/pipermail/general/2015-January/016311.html

The MarkLogic data directory /var/opt/MarkLogic wasn't owned by the daemon user

Answer (score 0):

Okay I got it to work.
The only difference I can see this time around was I followed this script (save the nginx stuff):

https://github.com/jmakeig/marklogic-bootstrapping/blob/master/digitalocean/bootstrap.sh